# Oracle BI distinct SUM aggregate

Tags: oracle11g, sum, distinct, aggregation, obiee

I have a problem with SUM aggregation in oracle BI (v 11.1).
The source table is an aggregate with columns  Contract, SubContract, ContractAmount, SubContrAmount like this:
[image]

I'm trying to make a report in Oracle BI Answers that will show a Amount(Value) of each contract. I also need a SUMMARY at the end:

[image]

When I put a SUM aggregation method in repository in Oracle BI Admin on column "ContractAmountOverall", it shows 3000$. It should be 1000$. I need to have a SUM aggregation method on this field to make a summary.
Is there a way to make the SUM aggregation with distinct clause in Oracle BI 11?
PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

```
select contract, max(contractAmountOverall)
from table1
grouping (contract)
```

Comment: MAX or AVG aggregation would work, but i need a SUM aggregation rule to get SUMMARY at the bottom of report...so SUM is needed in this case.

Comment: Maybe this: select contract, sum(contractAmountOverall) from table1 group by grouping sets(contract)

Comment: I need to do this on a BI Admin level and I think there is no possibility to change grouping in repository in BI Admin